# Java Generics (simple case, clear enigma for infering)

Tags: java, generics, types, constructor, inference

I have this class, just for the purpose of learning:

```
public class MyClass{ //Looking for a solution without making my class also generic <Type>  

    //Private Arraylist var to hold the value called myvar 

   public MyClass(ArrayList<MyDesiredType> incoming) {
        //CODE   myVar=incoming  
    }

    public MyDesiredType getType() {
        return myVar.get(0);
    }   
}
```

Is there any way to infer  in the incoming object from the constructor to the return type of the method without warnings and castings and loosing typesafeness, but most of all WITHOUT making the whole class GENERIC (seems redundant to me)? If not, why should I think this is not feasible for the compiler?

This is a reformulated question I already did, but it was my first one and I learned how to expose it clear because nobody understood. I tried to edit later the original question but everything was buried. I changed and simplified the example and try to put it easy. Original question: [Java Generics Silly Thing (Why cant I infer the type?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290218/java-generics-silly-thing-why-cant-i-infer-the-type).

If there is any problem just tell it to me and I will remove it.

Comment: Looking at the old question and answers, it seems to be made quite clear, that what you want to do is impossible. The real question is: Why don't you want to make `MyClass` generic?

Comment: Well I only see one answer speaking about the impossibility of constructor inference, more than half of them only speak about generics in the class and the other we are all giving themselves contradictory answers about the inference. I dont want to make MyClass generic because I want to know if theres some creative way of passing the type from inside, and because I think its annoying and unnecessary if you already got the type to specify it for instantiating the class. And if an ordinary method can infer, why should a constructor not be able to do it or passing it to a private variable?

Comment: There's actually one case where it would be theoretically impossible to infer the type and that would be if `incoming` would be `null`. But the compiler has no way of knowing if it is `null`, so this may be one actual argument of _why_ you are not allowed type inference in this way.

Comment: But it's not a problem when using ordinary method inference, in fact is not a problem with the constructor, my problem is trying to reach and preserve the type out of the constructor scope, which was very good analyzed by user "101000"

Comment: And its not impossible, I got it with casting and @supresswarning, but I think it should be implemented in the ocmpiler

Comment: What I meant is that `null` has type `void`, so inference wouldn't be possible, although I didn't thought this through, as this also doesn't work for generic methods; e.g. for `<T> T f(T t)` this: `A a = f(null);` will fail. But to your second comment: When you @suppresswarning and _explicitly_ typecast, then how is this type _inference_ anymore? You can also just use a non-generic `ArrayList`, return `Object`s and use typecasts (btw: this is actually what Java is doing under the hood) - but then you lose typesafety.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there is not. How would the compiler know what type to return? The generic type of ArrayList in the constructor will not be known during compile time. You either have to make the whole class generic or take another approach.

Consider this:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrList.add("FOO");
        Test test = new Test(arrList);
        String testStr = test.returnWhat();
        System.out.println("testStr");
    }

    private final List myList; //warning

    public <T> Test(List<T> ttype) {
        myList = ttype;
    }

    public <T> T returnWhat() {
        return (T) myList.get(0); //warning
    }
}
```

This works but gives you warnings on the marked lines. So, really there is no way to achieve what you are describing without making the whole class generic.
Because, what if:

```
public class Test {


 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrList.add("FOO");
        Test test = new Test(); // now what?
        String testStr = test.returnWhat(0); // no warning...
        JPanel p = test.returnWhat(0); // goes through without warning, real nice...
        test.returnWhat(0); // returns Object

        Test test2 = new Test(arrList);
        test2.addElement(new Object()); // boom, inserted object into list of string.
        String nono = test2.returnWhat(1); // the universe goes down. assign an object to string without warning. even
                                           // though one COULD think the class is generic.
    }

    // private List<T> myList = new ArrayList<T>(); compiler error, T is unknown
    private List myList = new ArrayList();

    public Test() {
        myList.add(new Object());
    }

    public <T> Test(List<T> ttype) {
        myList = ttype;
    }

    public <T> T returnWhat(int index) {
        return (T) myList.get(index);
    }

    public <T> void addElement(T el) {
        myList.add(el);
    }
}
```

The second one doesn't compile when myList is made generic. How could the compiler determine the type of <T> in the case where the default constructor is used?

Further, this could lead to serious problems with Objects in collections that rely on the fact that only certain types are inserted.

This will generate the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
java.lang.Object cannot be cast to java.lang.String     at
Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Did I manage to convince you?

Real nice question, btw. I had to think about this one quite a bit.

Comment: Why? if it works on methods why not in constructor? I can do the same with method inference, something like public <T> T getType(T incoming) with Java 6and use it. And for the constructor it says in Java Docs Note that constructors can be generic (in other words, declare their own formal type parameters) in both generic and non-generic classes. Consider the following example:

class MyClass<X> {
  <T> MyClass(T t) {
    // ...
  }
}

Comment: Thank you now I really see it, incredible answer. Thank you again!! The key I thing is in the addElement part more than others,or at least the one I didn´t think of.

Answer (score 2):

When you say that you want the compiler to "infer in the incoming object from the constructor to the return type of the method without warnings and castings and loosing typesafeness", it seems that you are saying that it should infer the result of `getType()` from the input of the constructor.  If both happen in the same function, it could.  The problem is that the object may not exist in only one function, and so the extra type information (the generic type) is needed to pass this kind of object between functions.

For example, if I want to write a function that takes a `MyClass` object, I need to know what `getType()` will return so I can use the returned value.  By adding a generic type of `MyClass` we are giving a description to what it holds.

Another way to look at it is that `MyClass` is a container.  By adding generics, we are saying it is a container of a specific type of thing, and so we can more easily predict what we will get out of it.

Comment: Sorry maybe Im not right syntactically. I like your answer the most, that´s all I know and all I wanted to know.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the compiler to know at runtime what type your arraylist is. I really dont see the problem using something along the lines of this:

```
 public class MyClass<TYPE> {
     private ArrayList<TYPE> incoming;

     public MyClass(ArrayList<TYPE> incoming) {
         this.incoming = incoming;
     }

     public TYPE getType() {
         return incoming.get(0);
     }
 }
```

This way you can do:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = createListOfNumbers();
MyClass<Integer> myClass = new MyClass<>(numbers);
Integer number = myClass.getType();
```

Or am i misinterpreting the question and you want to know the class at runtime?

Comment: Because I like the way the class would act like some kind of factory, and I think and maybe Im wrong that compiler shouldnt need the class type for infering it

Comment: With the way Id like to use the class, I would need to manually take the type from the ArrayList to pass it as a type to instantiate the Class. Imagine I dont have the info "Integer" in your second line, I receive and ArrayList and should look for the content for instantiating my class and then after pass it the arraylist with the type again, so why need doing it twice?

Comment: Thats the whole point of type safety, i think your missing the point of generics. If you dont want to infer a type, just dont use generics, you can retrieve class information from the object returned by MyClass.getType()

Answer (score 0):

**No,** if you want a class that can hold a list of a parameterized type.

**Yes,** if you want a class that can hold a list of exactly one type. You can declare that type explicitly in the field, constructor and accessor.

Comment: Thank you but I want to return ? where ? is what the arraylist carries so not concrete type (its concrete because the arralist contains only one type inside, but this arraylist can be different anytype). Just thought as last resort some way of using a private var to hold it as a wildcard but they already told me it´s not possible by design

Answer (score 0):

What you're forgetting is that not all code that you may run against is visible to the compiler!  Jars can be added, removed, substituted at run time, that the compiler never saw.  You may compile against an interface that is just:

```
public interface MyClassFactory {
  MyClass getInstance();
}
```

Then at runtime you supply into the JVM an implementation.  So the compiler never saw the actual code creating the MyClass that you will be using, so there is no way to perform such a compile time inference.  You must either make the class generic or accept that there will not be type safety.

Comment: Thanks but the inference  per se is done in the constructor the problem is I cannot get the type outside the scope of the constructor because there´s no return type and if I can do it in methods I think there should be some way of succeeding

Comment: The point is it's done compile time.  If the compiler can't see the constructor call, but does see you call the method (which can easily happen), then it has no way to make the connection.